# Calling a C++ class from inside another class

Tags: c++

I have a question I really hope someone can either help me with or point me in the right direction. Basically I have the following C++ code:

```
void ComparePackets::run_timer(Timer *)
{
    Packet *p = input(1).pull();
    if (p)
        p->kill();
    _timer.reschedule_after(_interval);
}
```

and I need to call/run this code from inside the following block of code:

```
void ComparePackets::check(Packet *p, Packet *p)
{
    bool different = false;
    if (p->length() != q->length())
    different = true;
    do
    {
        ////Insert code to call ComparePackets::run_timer(Timer *) code here///
    }
    while (p->length() == 106);
}
```

I have tried everything I know, (admittedly not much), but just keep getting error messages when I compile all of the code. The idea behind this snippet of code is to drop packets from one interface at preset intervals when packets of length 106 bytes appear on another interface. 
Any help greatly appreciated!

The ComparePackets class is:

```
class ComparePackets : public Element { public:

ComparePackets() CLICK_COLD;
//TimedSink() CLICK_COLD;

const char *class_name() const        { return "ComparePackets"; }
const char *port_count() const        { return "2/2"; }
const char *processing() const        { return PULL; }
//int configure(Vector<String> &, ErrorHandler *) CLICK_COLD;
int initialize(ErrorHandler *) CLICK_COLD;
void cleanup(CleanupStage) CLICK_COLD;
//void add_handlers() CLICK_COLD;

Packet *pull(int);
void run_timer(Timer *);///////////
```

private:

```
Packet *_p[2];
bool _available[2];
NotifierSignal _signal[2];

bool _timestamp : 1;
Timer _timer;///////////////////
Timestamp _interval;////////////////

//uint32_t _ndiff;
//enum { D_LEN, D_DATA, D_TIMESTAMP, D_NETOFF, D_NETLEN, D_NETHDR,
  // D_MORE_PACKETS_0, D_MORE_PACKETS_1, D_LAST };
//uint32_t _diff_details[D_LAST];

void check(Packet *, Packet *);
//static String read_handler(Element *, void *) CLICK_COLD;
//static int write_handler(const String &, Element *, void *, ErrorHandler *) CLICK_COLD;
```

};

Comment: Any reason not to use this->runTimer(arg) or just runTimer(arg) in the loop?

Comment: Could you also share the declaration of class `ComparePackets`?

Comment: twice use argument 'p' (is duplicated). IF YOU HAVE ERROR MESSAGE, here is important information, we cannot help without.

Comment: Hi User3147395, using this-> run_timer(arg) or run _Timer(arg) results in error messages. I tried Timer(arg) and it compiles, but crashes on running.

Answer (score 0):

you have double define for p !!

```
void ComparePackets::check(Packet *p, Packet *p)
```

fix:

```
void ComparePackets::check(Packet *p, Packet *q)
```

Comment: Many thanks آدم قنوات, that was a typo on my part, sorry for that.

Comment: the ComparePackets class is: